# dry code from sql to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have seven locations and 14 statuses.  I've hard-coded a lot of things and I want to make it DRY.  I made everything into an int array.  I tried to do some studying on enumerator but I wasn't sure on how exactly it'd fit.

At the moment, I need to show every location to count how many units with each status.

```
"SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A
,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B
,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C
,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS D
,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'E' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS E
,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS F
,SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'G' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS G...
FROM TABLE WHERE location1 = @location"
//..
                    int[] result = new int[15];
                    //..
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.Fill(ds);

                    foreach (DataRow dRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        result[0] = (int)dRow["A"];
                        result[1] = (int)dRow["B"];
                        result[2] = (int)dRow["C"];
                        result[3] = (int)dRow["D"];
                        result[4] = (int)dRow["E"];
                        //..
                    }
                    return result;
```

My Controller

```
    private IEquipmentDapper dapper = new EquipmentDapper();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        int[] AllLocationStatuses = dapper.CountAllStatuses();

        ViewBag.TotalA = AllLocationStatuses[0];
        ViewBag.TotalB = AllLocationStatuses[1];
        ViewBag.TotalC = AllLocationStatuses[2];
        ViewBag.TotalD = AllLocationStatuses[3];
        ViewBag.TotalE = AllLocationStatuses[4];
        //..
        int[] Location1Statuses = dapper.CountStatusesByLocation();

        ViewBag.Location1A = Location1Statuses[0];
        ViewBag.Location1B = Location1Statuses[1];
        ViewBag.Location1C = Location1Statuses[2];
        //..
```

And my view

```
    <td>Total</td>
    <td><span class="A"></span>@ViewBag.A A</td>
    <td><span class="B"></span>@ViewBag.B B</td>
    <td><span class="C"></span>@ViewBag.C C</td>
    <td><span class="D"></span>@ViewBag.D D</td>
```

Comment: So... what is the question here?

Comment: How do I shorten this code?

Comment: The `foreach` in the first block looks completely redundant since you only expect one row in the data set. It could probably be changed to an iterator for the columns. In the controller and view, you could probably just add the result array to the viewbag and then in the view do a @foreach to loop through all the results in the viewbag creating a span for each one.

Comment: Although it's not properly illustrated in my code, how do I also display the name of the status and its integer?

Comment: Its not clear from your code that you have a "name and integer" in the status. Also your SQL could probably be cleaned up using a group-by statement instead of a lot of sum/cases.

Comment: I would not be using ViewBag in this way.  You are abusing ViewBag